# Match two array associates keys and replace reference array key with 1st array

Tags: php, arrays, array-key

Match 1st and 2nd array associates keys. And replace 1st array associates keys with 2nd array value. Information like below.

```
1st Array

  [
        [ ],
        [ ],
       {
         585: {
               firsthalf: "0",
               secondhalf: "1",
               goals: "1",
               outcome: ["loss"]
              },
         625: {
               firsthalf: "2",
               secondhalf: "2",
               goals: "4",
               outcome: ["win"]
              }
         },
         {
          609: {
                firsthalf: "2",
                secondhalf: "0",
                goals: "2",
                outcome: ["win"]
               },
          625: {
                firsthalf: "0",
                secondhalf: "1",
                goals: "1",
                outcome: ["loss"]
               }
           },

2nd Array

       [
        {654: "North Geelong Warriors FC"},
        {645: "Springvale White Eagles FC"},
        {637: "Brunswick City Soccer Club"},
        {625: "Melbourne Victory Youth FC"},
        {585: "Moreland City FC"},
```

Final out come should be like this

```
Final Array
       [
        [ ],
        [ ],
       {
         Moreland City FC: {
               firsthalf: "0",
               secondhalf: "1",
               goals: "1",
               outcome: ["loss"]
              },
         Melbourne Victory Youth FC: {
               firsthalf: "2",
               secondhalf: "2",
               goals: "4",
               outcome: ["win"]
              }
         },
```

Comment: How did you tried to solve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replace array keys with given respective keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722988/replace-array-keys-with-given-respective-keys)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I have used below foreach for solution but need improvement on this 

  foreach($1stArray as $keys => $values)
{
    foreach($values as $key => $value){

            for ($x = 0; $x <= count($2ndArray); $x++) {
    $newkey = array_search($key,$2ndArray[$x]);
    $newkey = $key;
    unset ($key);
        }
}
}

Comment: Put code in the question, not in the comments.  It would also help if you explained the logic that produced the final array form the 1st one.  Ex why is there only one entry for Melbource Victory Youth Fc, when they are listed twice (team 625) in the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($Array01 as $keys => $values){
foreach($values as $key => $value){
        for ($x = 0; $x <= count($array02); $x++) {
            if (array_search($key, $array02[$x])){
                $newkey = array_search($key,$array02[$x]);
                $newArray[] = array($newkey => $value);
      }
    }
  }
}
print_r($$newArray);
```

This is been sort it out.